# Detecting a cycle in a directed graph using DFS?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

So, I was trying to find a cycle using DFS in a directed graph. Now, I know that if topological sort of a graph is not possible, then the graph contains a cycle. I made the following algorithm for topological sort. I am not sure where should I modify this code in order to `return true` or `false` and checking if my graph contains a cycle or not. Here is the algorithm that I use:

```
DFS-Loop (Graph G)

1. Mark all vertices as unexplored.
2. Set label = n // number of vertices
3. For each vertex V (belonging to) G
   -- If V not yet explored,
   -- DFS (G,V)
4. Set f(V) = current_label // here, f(V) is basically the position of V in the ordering
5. current_label-- 

Where DFS(G,V) will be something like: 

1. Mark V as explored.
2. For every vertex K belonging to Adj.(V)
   -- If K is not explored, 
   -- Call DFS(G,K)
```

Where should I add this check for containing a cycle or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

The simplest approach to find cycles in a directed graph is as follows.

Use *three* states of vertices: "not explored", "is being explored" and "fully explored". When you enter a new vertex, set it to "is being explored", and when you are done with a vertex, set it to "fully explored". Now, when you iterate over neighbors of some vertex, if you come to a vertex that "is being explored", then there is a cycle.

```
DFS(G,V):
1. Mark V as "being explored"
2. For every vertex K belonging to Adj.(V)
   -- If K is not explored, 
      -- Call DFS(G,K)
   -- else if K is "being explored" (not "fully explored")
      -- then there is a cycle
3. Mark V as "fully explored"
```

You can find the cycle by backtracking from the "being explored" vertex you found.

Another approach is just allow DFS-based topological sort to run and create some ordering of vertices. Now iterate over all edges and check that they are properly oriented. If all edges are properly oriented, then there if no cycles, otherwise there is at least one.

Comment: It should be `else if K is "fully explored"`. Your algorithm fails if I take a 2 node 1 edge graph. It will mark it as having a cycle.

Comment: @ManishSharma, note that the graph is directed

Answer (score 4):

For an undirected graph just follow these steps -

1) Instead of boolean visited array, make it int type with all indices initialised to -1.

Here -1 = **Not explored**,0 = **being explored**,1 = **Fully explored**

2) Initialise a global boolean variable flag as false.

Here true = **contains cycles**,false = **does not contain cycles**

3) Now write DFS as follows (following is a C++ code) -

```
void dfs(int s)
{
    visited[s] = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < adj[s].size(); i++)
    {
        if(visited[ adj[s][i] ] == -1)
        {
            dfs(adj[s][i]);
        }
        else if(visited[adj[s][i]] == 1)
        {
            flag = true;
            return;
        }
    }
    visited[s] = 1;
}
```

Comment: `visited[adj[s][i]] == 1` is incorrect it should be `visited[adj[s][i]] == 0`, that is while the vertex is being explored

Comment: @suraznegi the algorithm that I have written is for undirected graph in which case `visited[adj[s][i]] == 1` is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend reading the corresponding section in "Algorithms -- An introduction" (Cormen et. al).

Basically you need to detect, when you're revisiting a non-finished vertex:

Instead of labelling your vertices V as explored/unexplored you add an additional label state "currently_explored".
Each vertex is labeled unexplored in the beginning (as in the moment). But it is labeled "currently_explored" in Step 1 of your DFS (instead of explored) and marked explored AFTER the for-loop 2 in your DFS.

Before calling recursively in DFS you check the state. If it is unexplored, just call recursively (as currently). If it is currently_explored, you have detected a cycle! (It it is "explored" this is called a forward edge and of no further interest here).

Note, that this can be integrated into the topological sorting algorithm
(I'd recommend looking this up in the Cormen too).